# Read variable from anonymous Javascript function from devtools console

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to read a variable from a minified site script that is made of a huge anonymous function for reverse engineering purposes. As I understand it, it is not normally possible to access variables trapped inside this closure.

```
(function() {
  var af = function (a) { ... }
  var ge = function() {
      var obj = {};
      obj.foo = 'bar';
      af(obj);
  }
})();
```

However, I can do so by placing a breakpoint on a line inside of that scope.
Is there a way to reproduce this from Javascript in the developer console or some other way without modifying the script?

I've attempted hooking `Function.prototype.apply` but ran into infinite recursing paths.
The script redefines globals like `console` which makes this rather annoying.

Comment: You can probably define a setter for `foo` on Object.prototype.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to accomplish this, courtesy of [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom).

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "foo", {
    set: function(val) {
        console.log("Intercepted:", val);
        this._foo = val;
    },
    get: function() {
        return this._foo;
    }
});
```